# In akka tell, while actor is executing the logic and getting exception, what will happen to the thread executing the task

Tags: java, akka, playback

I have an actor connecting with database. When the actor is invoked on fire & forget model from the controller, we choosed tell method instead of ask. When there is an issue while performing DB operation, we get the exception. We do not capture the exception or having disciplined error handling there. So, in this situation, what would happen to the  connection with database as it is abruptly exited with the exception ? will that be dropped or still hanging and create struck thread. Please advise.

Also is it wise to ignore error handling when dealing with DB on using tell method to invoke Actor in Akka.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main principles of Akka Actor is *Let it crush*. So it is okay that the actor get an exception, it will be restarted by default by its supervisor. You can find more about fault tolerance in Akka in their documentation [fault-tolerance-akka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fault-tolerance.html)
So when there is an exception these are the 2 fast solutions it comes to my head for solving this issue:

1. **Retry strategy from the controller**: Not to use ask but inform supervisor when the DB operation has been performed without exceptions. The supervisor, in this occasion, the controller, can have tracked in a buffer the write operations that the actor have been requested to the actor. When the controller received the OK from the actor, it can remove it from the buffer, in another case if a response is not received in a timeout you can retry even if the actor has crushed due to the exception (mailRef of the actor will be the same and actor would have been restarted).
2. **Manage the exception **: You can manage the exception and treated in the supervisor after the actor crushed, depending on the exception you can define the actions to perform.

I would prefer the first option, but there is always this risk with fire & forget model. Another option but harder to implement is to add persistence to the actor and log the message as events. In that case, the actor will have that information it needs for retry the operation after crush.